# Question about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$.

Tags: probability, summation, irrational-numbers

In several places on this site the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(n)}{n}$ has been discussed as a generalized alternating series, which therefore converges. I am curious about the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$, which I am sure does **not** converge.  Here is my "proof".  Steps 2 and 3 clearly needs some clarification.

Step 1) Define $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ by $A:=[\pi/4,3\pi/4]\cup[5\pi/4,7\pi/4]\cup\ldots$.  For any $x\in A$, $|\sin(x)|\geq\sqrt{2}/2$.

Step 2) Since $\pi$ is irrational, roughly half the integers are in $A$.  That is, if we define $\#_A(n)$ to be the cardinality of $\{1,\ldots,n\}\cap A$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\#_A(n)}{n}=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Step 3) Therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|\sin(n)|}{n}>\sum_{n>0,n\in A}\dfrac{|\sin(n)|}{n}>\sum_{n>0,n\in A}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}/2}{n}\approx\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{\sqrt{2}/2}{n}$.

Step 4) Since the last sum in Step 3 diverges, the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$ diverges.

I beleive this is more or less intuitively right, but I do not really know the theory to make rigorous Steps 2 and 3.

Comment: For steps 2 and 3, I think the [Weyl equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) will do.

Comment: Take $A$ to be comprised of sets of the form $[n\pi/2-1/2, n\pi/2+1/2]$, $n$ odd. Then you can say each such interval contains an integer, and your idea will work out without problems.

Comment: @Did I don't think this is actually a duplicate of the other question, since the OP already knew the series diverged.

Comment: @user84413 But the answers there clarify the idea behind steps #2-#4 here.

Comment: @Did, thanks for the reference, I did not find that for some reason when looking at the possible duplicates.

Comment: @David Mitra, Good point.

Comment: @Did I guess you are right about this; it is related to the steps given above.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is almost correct, except that we need some justification. So here is the missing part:

> **Lemma.** If $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be such that $\sigma_{n} = (a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n})/n$ converges to $\alpha > 0$, then
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n} = \infty. \tag{1}$$

*Proof.* Let $s_{n} = a_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}$ denotes the partial sum. Then for $n \geq 2$,

$$ \frac{a_{n}}{n} = \sigma_{n} - \sigma_{n-1} + \frac{\sigma_{n-1}}{n}. $$

Consequently, we have

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{a_{n}}{n} = \sigma_{N} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{\sigma_{n}}{n+1}. $$

Using standard techniques, it is easy to see that

$$ \frac{1}{\log N} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{\sigma_{n}}{n+1} \xrightarrow[]{N\to\infty} \alpha. $$

Thus we have

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{a_{n}}{n} = (\alpha+o(1))\log N $$

and hence (1) follows. ////

Comment: Thank you for the lemma.  I follow your proof, but I am a little unclear on the application.  I suppose that we are using $a_n=|\sin(n)|$.  It is not clear to me why $\dfrac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\to\alpha>0$.  Are you using now my Step 2 here (which, according to Omnomnomnom follows from the Weyl equidistribution theorem)? From which it would follow I think that $\alpha\geq\sqrt{2}/{4}$?

Comment: @TrevorRichards, exactly. I am assuming that equidistribution theorem. So you can apply this lemma either to $a_{n} = 1_{A}(n)$ or to $a_{n} = |\sin n|$. (In the latter case, you also need [Weyl's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Riemann_integral_criterion_for_equidistribution).)

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x;- \pi \le x \le \pi$

$x \in \left[ { - \pi ;\pi } \right]; - x \in \left[ { - \pi ;\pi } \right]:f( - x) =  - f(x)$

$\forall n \in N:a_n= 0$

$b_n  = \frac{2}{\pi }\int\limits_0^\pi  {x\sin nxdx = }  - \frac{2}{{\pi n}}\left[ {x\cos nx} \right]_0^\pi$

$ b_n  =  - \frac{2}{{n\pi }}\left[ {x\cos nx} \right]_0^\pi   = \frac{2}{n}\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 1}$

$f(x) = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 1} \sin nx}}{n}}  $

$x\in\left] { - \pi ;\pi } \right]:\frac{x}{2} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 1} \frac{{\sin nx}}{n}}$

$ t \in \left] {0;2\pi } \right]:\left( {\pi  - t} \right) \in \left] { - \pi ;\pi } \right]$

if pose  $x = \pi  - t$

$\displaylines{
  \sin \left( {n\left( {\pi  - t} \right)} \right) = \cos n\pi \sin \left( { - nt} \right) + \sin n\pi \cos \left( { - nt} \right) \cr 
   = \left( { - 1} \right)^n \sin \left( { - nt} \right) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 1} \sin \left( {nt} \right) \cr}$

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sin nt}}{n}}  = \frac{{\pi  - t}}{2};\forall t \in \left] {0;2\pi } \right]$
t=1
$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sin n}}{n}}  = \frac{{\pi  - 1}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that the intervals $\left(\frac{(4n-1)\pi}{4},\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{4}\right)$ have length $\frac{\pi}{2}<2$,

so there can't be 3 consecutive integers in any of these intervals;

so $S_{3n}=\frac{|\sin 1|}{1}+\frac{|\sin 2|}{2}+\frac{|\sin3|}{3}+\cdots+\frac{|\sin 3n|}{3n}\ge\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n}\right)\to\infty$.

---

Another argument you could use  is that

$\displaystyle\frac{|\sin n|}{n}\ge\frac{\sin^2 n}{n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2n)}{n}\ge0$ for all n, and

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges while $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos2n}{n}$ converges by Dirichlet's test,

so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin n|}{n}$ diverges by the Comparison Test.